# Class and id don't seem to be working for an h1 with my css file

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why this won't work. I happen to be using bootstrap as well.

```
<h1 class="montserrat_text" id="header_title">title</h1>
```

In the css file .montserrat_text works and the font of the h1 is the correct font.

But when I add #header_title to the css:

```
#header_title
{

 color: red;
 font-size: 60px;

}
```

Nothing happens and the text won't change size or color.

Thanks

Comment: Its `color`, not `font-color`.

Comment: you must know basic css properties

Comment: yeah sorry about the font-color, in my css i had it as color

Comment: Did you check the css for .montserrat_text if there is any color or font size properties with !important? If so, you need to remove the !important from it so that it will use the id's css properties instead.

Answer (score 4):

The reasons the font color doesn't change was mentioned by @MohammadUsman already - there is no CSS property called `font-color`, what you want is named `color`.

The reasons the `font-size` doesn't change either (even though the property name is correct) could be that your browser ignores rules that follow illegal rules.

Answer (score 2):

For change the color of text you must use **color** instead of **font-color**.

According to **CSS priority** if a selector contain the parents name , this selector has priority for effect than selector that does not contain it.

You must use parent name in selector like :

```
{# or .}parent #header_title
{
 color: red;
 font-size: 60px !important;
}
```

or you can use **!important** :

```
#header_title
{
 color: red;
 font-size: 60px !important;
}
```

Comment: That was an error on my part when I wrote out my css here...i was actually using color in my css and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you explain to me please why you need to use {# or .}parent #header_title and you can't just use #header_title?

Comment: do you know that you must change "{# or .}parent" with a valid selector? also likely color not affect because css priority.

Comment: because if you mention the parent name your selector has priority from other selector that effects on "#header_title" or "h1". for example if you have selector "#parent h1#header_title{color:#fff}" and "#header_title{color:#000}" , first selector is effect and h1 will be white color.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mohammed Usman said, it's `color`, not `font-color`.
Also, since you're using Bootstrap, it's possible something is overriding your CSS so you can add the `!important` tag to ensure that your CSS is used, as so:

```
#header_title {
 color: red !important;
 font-size: 60px !important;
}
```

Comment: `!important` can be used for testing purposes, but never on actual production CSS.

Comment: That's silly- it depends on the project. Though it's better not to use it, sometimes it's better just to get something done quickly with minimal hassle and this provides that option.